# Sizable input file and submit button on same line

Tags: html, css

I want to display a label, an input file and a submit button on the same line. The input file needs to be sizable (this means it will change size when the parent changes size and NOT dragable to resize). I tried to use display: table and display: table-cell and for some reason it works for other combinations but not this one

```html
    <div style="display:table;">
        <label style="display: table-cell; width: 80px;">Text</label>
        <input type="file" style="display:table-cell; width: 100%;"/>
        <input style="display: table-cell; width:50px;" type="submit" value = "Upload"/>
    </div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/danbenedek/wxn976oe/2/

Here is the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danbenedek/un9qae0x/1/ from where I got inspired but all the elements are div and it works. The moment I changed them to label and input it stop working.

Comment: What you mean: sizable?

Comment: If you resize the window the input file should change size. I need the 3 elements to be on the same line: the label and the submit to be autosize based on the content and the input file to fill the rest of the width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/wxn976oe/4/

```css
.Column {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
label.Column {
    width: 80px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    width: 50px;
}
input[type="file"] {
    width: calc(100% - (80px + 50px));
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
    <label class="Column">Text</label>
    <input class="Column" type="file"/>
    <input class="Column" type="submit" value = "Upload"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Partially yes. But can this be achieved without knowing the label and button size? The same label can have different texts in it so the width 80 and 50 were only for example.

Comment: I Think it's not possible with pure css, you can do it with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet. I hope this is what you are looking.

```css
.Row {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  float: left;
}

.Column {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  resize:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <label class="Column">Text</label>
  <input class="Column" type="file" />
  <input class="Column" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

Comment: The input file is not sizable. I want it to be. That was the reason I used the table display

Comment: try adding `resize:both;` to css @Dan

Comment: @@Edison for me sizable does not mean that the user can drag the item to resize it. It means that it changes size when the content changes size

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the following snippet and I think the issue your facing will be resolved.

```css
.Column {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <label class="Column">Text</label>
  <input class="Column" type="file" />
  <input class="Column" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```css
.Column {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <label class="Column" style="width: 80px;">Text</label>
  <input class="Column" type="file" />
  <input class="Column" style="width:50px;" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</div>
```